# Annotations won't appear on MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm having trouble getting my annotations to display on my map view. Nothing is displaying right now. What is wrong with my code ?

Here is my base map view controller:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

let goldenWordsYellow = UIColor(red: 247.00/255.0, green: 192.00/255.0, blue: 51.00/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

// Map View outlet declaration
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

// Hamburger button declaration
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

/* Really ugly code where I declare all of my static data */
let coordinatesARC = IssueLocation(locationName: "ARC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49416565895079, longitude: 44.22928743712073))
let coordinatesJDUC = IssueLocation(locationName: "JDUC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49507761001587, longitude: 44.22838027067406))
let coordinatesStaufferLibrary = IssueLocation(locationName: "Stauffer Library", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49615049362183, longitude: 44.228418710213944))
let coordinatesWalterLightHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Walter Light Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49166584014893, longitude: 44.22794205814507))
let coordinatesDupuisHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Dupuis Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.4927065372467, longitude: 44.22867241054762))
let coordinatesHumphreyHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Humphrey Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49212718009949, longitude: 44.22688879714365))
let coordinatesBiosciencesComplex = IssueLocation(locationName: "Biosciences Complex", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49117231369019, longitude: 44.226327562781904))
let coordinatesBMH = IssueLocation(locationName: "Beamish-Munro Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49271726608276, longitude: 44.228195760533175))
let coordinatesBotterellHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Botterell Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49160146713257, longitude: 44.22447468258034))
let coordinatesEtheringtonHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Etherington Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49390816688538, longitude: 44.224282471751785))
let coordinatesJefferyHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Jeffery Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49605393409729, longitude: 44.22590855555731))
let coordinatesEllisHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Ellis Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49602174758911, longitude: 44.22636984774898))
let coordinatesMackintoshCorryHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Mackintosh-Corry Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49697124958038, longitude: 44.22677731951135))
let coordinatesChernoffHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Chernoff Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49884343147278, longitude: 44.22436704459368))
let coordinatesLeggetHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Legget Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49749159812927, longitude: 44.22362126170883))
let coordinatesLeonardHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Leonard Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.50065660476685, longitude: 44.22429016019697))
let coordinatesVictoriaHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Victoria Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49863958358765, longitude: 44.22550492192426))
let coordinatesStirlingHall = IssueLocation(locationName: "Stirling Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49767398834229, longitude: 44.22463613919133))
let coordinatesWestCampus = IssueLocation(locationName: "West Campus", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.51471138000487, longitude: 44.22438242146097))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hamburger button configuration
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    // Setting the Map type to standard
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard

    // Configuring locationManager and mapView delegate
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Set the center of campus as the first location, before we show the actual user location
    let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.226181, longitude: -76.495614)
    let latitudeDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.015
    let longitudeDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.015
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(initialLocation, span)

    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

    let ARCAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    ARCAnnotation.title = coordinatesARC.locationName
    ARCAnnotation.subtitle = coordinatesARC.locationName
    ARCAnnotation.coordinate = coordinatesARC.coordinate

    mapView.addAnnotation(ARCAnnotation)

    // Adding all annotations to the map view
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesARC)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesJDUC)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesStaufferLibrary)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesWalterLightHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesDupuisHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesHumphreyHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesBiosciencesComplex)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesBMH)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesBotterellHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesEtheringtonHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesJefferyHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesEllisHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesMackintoshCorryHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesChernoffHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesLeggetHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesLeonardHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesVictoriaHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesStirlingHall)
    mapView.addAnnotation(coordinatesWestCampus)

 mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.226181, longitude: -76.495614)
}

 func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
     } else {
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is my map view controller extension:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension MapViewController {



func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? IssueLocation {
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation // NOTE: 2 options here for the "annotation" at the end of this line. I choose the first one but am in doubt.
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier) // NOTE: another unsure choice for the "annotation" right before the comma
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView
        }

        return view
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let location = view.annotation as! IssueLocation
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking]
    location.mapItem().openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
}

}
```

And here is my class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import AddressBook
import Contacts

class IssueLocation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

let locationName: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(locationName: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    self.locationName = locationName
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()

}

var subtitle: String? {
    return locationName
}

var title: String? {
    return locationName
}

func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {

    let addressDictionary = [String(CNPostalAddressStreetKey): locationName]

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = locationName

    return mapItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with your coordinates.

Your code:

```
let coordinatesARC = IssueLocation(locationName: "ARC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49416565895079, longitude: 44.22928743712073))
let coordinatesJDUC = IssueLocation(locationName: "JDUC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -76.49507761001587, longitude: 44.22838027067406))
```

Corrected code:

```
 let coordinatesARC = IssueLocation(locationName: "ARC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.22928743712073, longitude: -76.49416565895079))
let coordinatesJDUC = IssueLocation(locationName: "JDUC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.22838027067406, longitude: -76.49507761001587))
```

Comment: I ended up being able to fix it (in the same way you fixed it), but thanks anyways. When I realized that my coordinates pointed to Antarctica, I thought something was up :P

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the up vote and marking this as the answer. Also like how your code functions, great job on all the other coding.